# App Engine query in admin datastore viewer returning different results than programmatic query

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, models

I'm flummoxed.

I noticed today that some data I thought should be present in my production appengine app wasn't showing up. I connected to the app via the remote console and ran the queries manually. Sure enough it looked like I only had 15 of the 101 rows I was expecting to see.

Then I went to my admin console at appengine.google.com and fired up the datastore viewer with the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM Assignment where game = KEY('Game', '201212-foo') and player = KEY('Player', 'player-mb')
```

The result I see is the first page of 20 results. I page through those results, and am able to see all 101 entities. HOORAY! My data is still there. BUT why then can't I access it via the db api?  (NOTE: I've already tried clearing memcache via the memcache viewer, even though this particularly query isn't manually memcached)

From the remote console:

```
> from google.appengine.ext.db import GqlQuery
> GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Assignment WHERE game = KEY('Game', '201212-foo') and player = KEY('Player', 'player-mb')").count()
15
```

The remote console agrees with the app itself, which only seems to be able to see 15 of the expected 101 rows.

What gives?

**UPDATE**:

I suspect this might be an indexing issue. If I issue get_by_key_name for one of the missing rows, it subsequently shows up in db api queries.

```
> GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Assignment WHERE game = KEY('Game', '201212-foo') and player = KEY('Player', 'player-mb')").count()
15
> entities.Assignment.get_by_key_name('201212-assignment-135.9')
<entities.Assignment object at 0xa11eb6c>
> GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Assignment WHERE game = KEY('Game', '201212-foo') and player = KEY('Player', 'player-mb')").count()
16
```

So should I (or can I) rebuild my indexes to remedy this problem?

**UPDATE #2**:

I attempted to build a perfect index for this query, and have just verified that even when the query does use the just-built index (via query.index_list()), the results are still only limited to a small subset of items available via the datastore viewer. Infuriatingly, it's actually a different subset than is available with the previous index (20 items vs 15  items). So now adding an additional filter term results in an additional 5 rows returned. So dumb.

All indexes claim to be "serving" so there shouldn't be any reason that the indexes are this far off.

**UPDATE #3**:

Sometimes, using my new index, I'll get the right answer:

```
> GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Assignment WHERE game = KEY('Game', '201212-foo') and player = KEY('Player', 'player-mb') and user = 'zee'").count()
101
```

However if I issue this query 10 times, it comes back with the 'bad' results about half the time:

```
> GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Assignment WHERE game = KEY('Game', '201212-foo') and player = KEY('Player', 'player-mb') and user = 'zee'").count()
16
```

So maybe its an issue of a bad/behind bigtable replica that I'm hitting half the time, or something else completely opaque that we won't get an answer to (appengine [status](http://code.google.com/status/appengine) does list a service disruption today), but I have a feeling that this will be fixed on its own. Will update again if it does.

**FINAL UPDATE**:

As I suspected, when I woke up this morning my app (and manual queries) now see a consistent, correct view of the data. Would still love an answer as to why this happened, but until I get that I'm going to chalk it up to internal Google bigtable weirdness.

I filed [this](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=9456) issue against appengine to see if I can get an answer from someone in the know.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue with my application.

The datastore query in DatastoreViewer returns a set of objects:
SELECT * FROM Article

However, articles = Article.query() in the script returns nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For HRD applications, this is working as intended. App Engine High Replication Datastore (HRD) stores your data synchronously in multiple datacenters. However, the delay from the time a write is committed until it becomes visible in all datacenters means that queries across multiple entity groups (non-ancestor queries) can only guarantee [eventually consistent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eventual_consistency) results. [1]

In your specific case, the discrepancy between the results from your application and the Admin Console Datastore Viewer is just because they most likely are reading from different Datastore servers with different consistency.

If you require a consistent view of your data, I advise taking a closer look into the article ["Structuring Data for Strong Consistency"](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency)

[1] https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency