# Google app engine query returns empty result

Tags: google-app-engine

I'm running a Kind based Query using Java API on GAE. 
Here is the sample code:

```
DatastoreService dataStore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();

        Filter value1Filter = new FilterPredicate(PROPERTY_1, FilterOperator.EQUAL, value1);
        Filter value2Filter = new FilterPredicate(PROPERTY_2, FilterOperator.EQUAL, value2);
        Filter myFilter = CompositeFilterOperator.and(value1Filter, value2Filter);

        Query findQuery = new Query("MyKIND").setFilter(myFilter);
        myEntity = dataStore.prepare(findQuery).asSingleEntity();
```

PROPERTY_1 and PROPERTY_2 are indexed properties. This query works some times and now fails consistently for certain values. Let's say these values are value1 and value2 shown above.

However, if I run the same query using SELECT in the datastore viewer with same values, value1 and value2, it works and shows the result. I earlier suspected this to be a result of eventual consistency. However, the indexed values have been written long back (months earlier) for them to be replicated across the other instances.

Is there a way to correct this situation? Unfortunately, I don't have the key of the entity to query with.

Comment: Your code looks correct. The problem is somewhere else - check that you are passing the correct values, etc.

Comment: Values are passed properly. This seems to be an issue with eventual consistency. However, my concern is with HRD lagging so behind in replication. I found my issue similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16973494/app-engine-query-in-admin-datastore-viewer-returning-different-results-than-prog However, since the replication should have happened long ago, wondering what else could be the issue.

Comment: Eventual consistency resolves within a few seconds at most.

Comment: It turned out to be a logical issue with asSingleEntity throwing a TooManyResultsException, however, the exception block not printing it because the getMessage() was NULL. The printStackTrace() function did not print anything causing us to follow a wrong lead. Thank you Andrei for your help.